# Uploading Large Files with Pure HTML and MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html

I have an application that allows users to upload files. Some of these files may be quite large. Because of this, I want to chunk up the file (if possible) and monitor its upload progress. Currently, I have a basic HTML form that posts back to my MVC controller

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UploadFile(IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
  // Save file here.
  HttpStatusCodeResult result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
  return result;
}
```

This approach allows me to upload a file. However, this appoach is one single opeation. I need to be able to kick off an upload and monitor its progress. Uploadify will not work in my case because it uses Flash. I have a strict No-Flash requirement.

I'm open to a hybrid approach where, if the user's browser supports HTML 5, I would use the File API, otherwise, I would use my current approach. However, even with HTML 5, I'm not sure how to kick off an upload and monitor its progress.

Can someone help me out?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may take a look at [Valums AJAX upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/). Personally I have used it many times and am very satisfied with it.

> **Features**
>
> - multiple file select, progress-bar in FF, Chrome, Safari
> - drag-and-drop file select in FF, Chrome
> - uploads are cancellable
> - no external dependencies
> - doesn't use Flash
> - fully working with https
> - keyboard support in FF, Chrome, Safari
> - tested in IE7,8; Firefox 3,3.6,4; Safari4,5; Chrome; Opera10.60;

Answer (score 2):

I've had a good experience with [Plupload](http://plupload.com/). It plays nice with jQuery UI as well.

Here are some higlighted features:

- Chunking
- Drag/Drop
- PNG Resize
- JPEG Resize
- Type filtering
- Stream upload
- Multipart upload
- File size restriction
- Upload progress
- Custom headers

It supports the following plugins/technologies for near complete cross browser usage (with varying degrees of feature support):

- Flash
- Gears
- HTML 5
- Silverlight
- BrowserPlus
- HTML 4